# ShapeSheet formula for resizing only the parent shape not the sub shapes of the parent shape

Tags: visio, shapesheet

A parent shape has 3 sub shapes in it. When parent shape is resized the sub shapes(3) are also getting resized. So, when I resize the parent shape only particular sub shapes should resize not all. What ShapeSheet formula is required for the above situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `ResizeMode` cell to achieve this.  For the sub-shapes you'll generally use the default (0) and this tells the shapes to use the `ResizeMode` value that's been set in the group shape.  You can therefore set the group's `ResizeMode` cell to 1, which tells it to use repositioning only.

Here's a list of the values [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/resizemode-cell-shape-transform-section):

> - 0  Use group's setting  -  visXFormResizeDontCare
> - 1  Reposition only  -  visXFormResizeSpread
> - 2  Scale with group  -  visXFormResizeScale

If you want the sub-shapes use different behaviours then you can set the cell in each sub-shape accordingly.

Under the covers, using a value of 1, the `Width` and `Height` cells are set as absolute values, while 2 (and the default for group shapes) sets relative values.  These are set when the shapes are added to the group, so you need to ensure the `ResizeMode` values are set first.

Answer (score 2):

Each sub-shape will have to have its width and height formula values changed. Open the shapesheet editor for each sub-shape that you don't want to have resize, if you want the sub-shape width to always be 20mm then set the **Width** cell **=GUARD(20mm)**. Similar for the **Height** cell.

Comment: When i modify the parent shape the sub shapes position should always be in touch with other sub shapes.

Comment: @sai-mourya. You should start a new question for that.